# Rock climbing around Seattle area

Tags: rock-climbing

I recently moved to Seattle from the bay area. Does anyone have any recommendations on climbing areas close to Seattle. I know of Index, but I have heard it's pretty hard. I am more of a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Agree with that, Index is the place be for high-quality trad on this side of the mountain. There is some trad in north bend, not with the best quality but yes exist. There are a couple of moderate lines at Exit 32 and also at Exit 38.
Some from Exit 32 -  Repo Climbing wall,
and in Exit 38 - Peannacle Climbing Wall, Shangri La Climbing

Answer (score 0):

You will find this blog useful.
https://www.miyaradventures.com/blog/guide-to-seattle-rock-climbing-and-courses/

It has a list of the rock climbing areas close to Seattle along with some general info/guidebooks.

Comment: Hi Mark, and welcome to TGO. To improve your answer consider adding a summary of some of the key points from the blog post you link. This way your answer is self-contained. Who knows what will happen to the blog down the road, so it is always good to have the relevant answer immortalized on TGO directly.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. That link is indeed very helpful. I went to exit 38  today and found some good climbs. Rock is very slippery though.